# Pulseaudio loopback changing source when new source is connected

Tags: pulseaudio, xubuntu

I have an audio stream coming in from line-in that I prefer to have monitored at all times. I use the following command to do this:

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source='alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'
```

and every time I connect any additional audio source (webcam, usb mic, etc) it changes to that source... resulting in near ear-bleed levels of feedback causing me to either rip the source out as quickly as possible or unload the module and execute the command again.

*I'm naming the source in this command...* why does it keep *changing* when new sources are connected? How do I permanently add a loopback of a specified device THAT WONT CHANGE?

Edit: System details: Asus Prime Z370-A motherboard, i7-8700K, Xubuntu 17.10.1, 4.13.0-38-generic

Comment: Tried commenting out "load-module module-switch-on-connect" in /etc/pulse/default.pa and had no effect. Thought that would have done it, but I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Anyone? Hard to believe no one has run into this...